# ¿Como organizar un array?

Tags: java, array, algoritmos

¿Cómo hago para que este programa me organice los datos en el mismo `Array` de modo que primero estén los números mayores a 0 y después los ceros en el método `Ordenar()`?  Por ejemplo:

**Entrada**

> (2,3,0,1,0)

**Salida**

> (2,3,1,0,0)

Aquí posteo el código que llevo

```
Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);

    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        System.out.print("ingrese posicion["+i+"]=");
        a[i]=leer.nextInt();
    }
    Ordenar();
}//main

static public void Ordenar(){
    //Código que necesito
}
```

Comment: Por la forma que esta escrito el codigo, no conviene ir ordenandolo a medida que llega? Digo tal vez es mas facil tener 2 arreglos y despues pegarlos. si es 0 va a un arreglos de 0 (o los cuentas y despues lo armas) y todo lo que no sea 0 va al arreglo comun.

Comment: Sería bueno que aclararas si tiene importancia el orden del `2,3,1` en tu ejemplo, o simplemente es cuestion de que los ceros queden a la derecha, y los otros numeros a la izquierda sin importar su orden.

Comment: @sstan Ya da un poco igual, tiene respuestas para aburrir :)

Comment: Con lo que pones en tu primer comentario entonces prescindirías del método ordenar porque nunca lo usarías si ya lo generas ordenado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día Camilo, para organizar un Array existen diferentes métodos de ordenamiento ya definidos, [aquí](http://enrrike87.blogspot.com/2011/06/metodos-de-ordenamiento-java_21.html) te dejo un artículo sobre eso y su implementación en Java. Después, a lo que veo en tu ejemplo solo necesitas el cambiar los ceros de posición. por lo que yo recomendaría una modificación del método burbuja, que sería así

```
public static void burbuja(int[]matrix){
        int temp;
        for(int i=1;i < matrix.length;i++){
            for (int j=0 ; j < matrix.length- 1; j++){
                if (matrix[j] == 0){
                    temp = matrix[j];
                    matrix[j] = matrix[j+1];
                    matrix[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Entrada**

> (2,3,0,1,0)

**Salida**

> (2,3,1,0,0)

Aquí te dejo el código ya probado, [link](http://ideone.com/Zvsqf3).

Answer (score 4):

Lo que entiendo es que no quieres un "sort" tradicional, si no que simplemente deseas que los `0` se encuentren al final, mientras que los demás números ***preservan*** su órden en el array.

Un método de hacerlo es en 2 etapas:

1. Correr todos los números que no son cero hacia la izquierda.
2. Llenar el resto del array con ceros.

Este método solo requiere un máximo de `array.length x 2` iteraciones en el peor de los casos, por lo que no es muy costoso.

**Código:**

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    int[] a = new int[] {0,0,2,3,0,0,0,1,0,4};

    // Primer pase, correr los numeros que no son cero a la izquierda.
    int lastNonZeroIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] != 0) {
            if (i != lastNonZeroIndex) {
                a[lastNonZeroIndex] = a[i];
            }
            lastNonZeroIndex++;
        }
    }

    // Segundo pase, llenar el resto del array con ceros.
    for (int i = lastNonZeroIndex; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = 0;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

**Resultado:**

> [2, 3, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: si hay dos ceros seguidos este algoritmo no anda. cambia un cero por el otro y no vuelve a corregirlo

Comment: @gbianchi: He modificado el algoritmo. Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Después de publicar mi respuesta me he dado cuenta de que es muy parecida a la tuya. Sin embargo, yo inicializo el array directamente en vez de poner luego los ceros :D

Answer (score 2):

Puedes inicializar el array en el que vas a guardar los datos ya que de esta manera te aseguras que todos los valores van a ser 0 por defecto.

```
int[] a = new int[5];
```

Luego solamente tienes que guardar la última posición en la que ha salido un número mayor que cero y guardar en esa posición el nuevo valor mayor que cero que ha entrado. Una vez hecho esto, sumarle uno para que el siguiente valor mayor que cero se inserte en la nueva `ultimaPosicion`.

El programa completo quedaría:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
         int[] a = new int[5];
         int ultimaPosicion = 0;
         int numero; 

         /* ORDENACIÓN */ 
         for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Introduce un número");
            numero = leer.nextInt();
            if(numero != 0){
                a[ultimaPosicion] = numero;
                ultimaPosicion++;
            }
         }

         /* COMPROBAR QUE EL ARRAY ESTÁ ORDENADO */
         for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
             System.out.print(a[j] + " ");
         }
    }
```

De esta manera, te puedes ahorrar el método Ordenar y hacer el ordenamiento directamente en la entrada de los datos.

Para la entrada:

> 0 2 0 5 4

Tendrías la salida:

> 2 5 4 0 0

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar `public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` y crear un comparador que haga lo que quieres. Una implementación sería esta:

```
int[] array = new int[]{2,3,0,1,0};

    Array array2 = new Array<Integer>();
    for(int i : array){
        array2.add(i);
    }

    array2.sort(new Comparator(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Integer)o1 == 0)?1:-1;
        }

    });

    System.out.println(array2);
```

La salida es:

> [1, 3, 2, 0, 0]

Answer (score 0):

Según la situación que planteas, el arreglo necesitas ordenarlo después de haberlo leído. Es decir no lo tenías salvado previamente, sólo conoces su longitud. En este caso puedes leerlo de manera conveniente y mantener una complejidad lineal O(n) a tu funcion.

```
  Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);

  int a_len = 10, j = 0;  
  int[] a = new int[a_len]; // Inicialmente todos los valores son 0

  for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      System.out.print("ingrese posicion["+i+"]=");
      a[j]=leer.nextInt();  // Lees en la última posición donde había un 0

      // Ordenar

      if(a[j] != 0)
         ++j;

      // Ordenar
  }
}//main
```