# Pasar datos de una matriz a un vector

Tags: java

Tengo un problema, tengo una matriz `5x5` con números aleatorios de 0 a 1000, debo tomar los números impares de la matriz, añadirlos a un vector y retornar ese vector.

Este es el método que debería retornar el vector con los números impares

```
public int[] s() {
    for(int i = 0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; i < matriz.length; j++) {
            if(matriz[i][j] % 2 != 0) {
                vector[cont] = matriz[i][j]; 
                cont++; 
            }
        }
    }
    return vector;
}
```

La variable **cont** esta inicializada en 0 y el tamaño del vector es la multiplicación de las filas y columnas.

Pero tengo una excepción que es la siguiente:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   5"

Supongo que hay un indice ilegal pero no encuentro la manera de arreglarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el segundo `for` la comparación debería ser en base a `J` si no el `for` más interno haría mostrar esta exceptión ya que en la primera iteración del for externo `i= 0` y como en el `for` más interno nunca cambia el valor de `i` la condición siempre será verdadera, pero `J` seguirá avanzando hasta ser `i =0` ; `J=6` y arroja la exception  en `matriz[i][j]`.Además debería obtener el `length` de la fila actual.

```
for(int i = 0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
    // remplazamos i por j , condición del for
    for(int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
        if(matriz[i][j] % 2 != 0) {
            vector[cont] = matriz[i][j]; 
            cont++; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si, me acabo de enterar.

Comment: Por alguna razón, sabes como aplicar el bubble sort a un Vector (la clase) que contiene números. Cambie el array por un Vector, retorno el Vector y me funciona. Sin embargo quiero organizar los numeros que contiene de manera ascendente.

Comment: @mb0 [Ya hay algunas preguntas de como ordenar arrays , una es esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31362/como-organizar-un-array/31371#31371)  y quizá hay más. Me alegro que haya solucionado su problema , Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucho cabeza y una ardua investigación llegue a esta solución

[image: Solución al problema de convertir una matriz en un vector]

Espero que te funcione, por que a mi me funciona increíble mente bien

Comment: seria ideal que cambiaras la imagen a código